# number of ways to combine k sorted lists of n/k elements to one sorted list of size n

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to solve a problem involving an algorithm that merges k sorted lists of distinct elements of size n/k to one sorted list of size n. Iv'e run into the problem of determining how many permutations the final list can have. Worth mentioning, I have no background in combinatorics. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to keep each sublist in order?  It seems likely.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to determine how many permutations the final list can have?  Since the algorithm produces a "sorted list of size $n$", the question is interesting only in the presence of duplicates, so some detail about what the algorithm does with duplicates (either in the same sublist or in different sublists) would be crucial to answering.

Comment: @hardmath I'm trying to obtain a lower bound for any comparison based algorithm that performs this task. The reason I asked the original question was to determine the minimal number of leaves the decision tree for this algorithm can have and deduce the minimal height of that tree (minimal number of comparisons) for any algorithm

Comment: The Question seems ask how many "ways" the outcome can occur, which as I noted is only greater than one if duplicates are present among the lists.  Now your Comment suggests a focus on counting comparisons or at least a lower bound on their number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=\frac nk$ to save typing.  Assuming you have to keep each sublist in order, take the first sublist and pick the places its elements go in the final list.  You can do that in $n \choose m$ ways.  Now take the second sublist and pick the places its elements go, which you can do in ${n-m \choose m}$ ways and so on.  The final count of permutations has $k$ factors and is $${n \choose m}{n-m \choose m}{n-2m \choose m}\ldots {m \choose m}$$

Another way to see it is that the $m$ elements of the first sublist are restricted to one permutation in their places instead of $m!$.  So are the elements of the second sublist and so on.  This gives $$\frac {n!}{(m!)^k}$$ orders.  If you expand the binomial coefficients above you can prove these two expressions are equal.